# Get current windows authenticated user from Active Directory in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have a web application where the user needs permission on create/edit/delete post actions. The permissions are handled in a custom table in the database based on windows username and custom role name.

This is my code:

```
var username = Environment.UserName;

using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var roleName = accessRepository.GetRole(username);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName) || roleName != Roles.admin.ToString())
        {
            hasAccess = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hasAccess = false;
    }

    if (!hasAccess)
    {
        // redirect
    }
}
```

In web.config I have

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

and I have tried setting

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

But it doesn't work. On the server I have tried setting the IIS to enable Asp.Net Impersonate and Anonymous Access and Windows Authentications in all variations of the three.

When I run this locally on my machine there's no problem, `username` is the username from my windows authentication from when I logged on to my machine.

But when I upload this to the server and go to the website on my local machine the `username` is the username from the server but not from my local machine.

Just to be clear, I don't want the user to log in to the web application. I want the web application to find out the windows authentication from active directory.

Is this not possible? Or am I not thinking it right?

Comment: it seems you enabled anonymous authentication in IIS.. check it out

Answer (score 2):

> Just to be clear, I don't want the user to log in to the web
>   application. I want the web application to find out the windows
>   authentication from active directory.

This is the part that doesn't quite make sense. The only way to find out the user's AD account is if they authenticate with your application. They won't have to type in their credentials - but their credentials still get sent to your server and your server verifies they are correct. So in that sense, they are being "logged in".

This is achieved with Windows authentication. You are on the right track with this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

But make sure you also disable anonymous authentication. Then you can access the username of the user like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

That will be in the format of DOMAIN\Username.

As a side note, `Environment.UserName` gets the username that the current thread is running under - basically, the credentials IIS is running under. On your development machine, that's your username (probably because you're using IIS Express). But on the server, it will be different.

Comment: May not have been clear. I don't want the website to ask the user for username and password. I thought there was a way for the website/server to retrieve the windows authentication from the machine the user is running on. Is that incorrect? Now I have Anonymous and Windows authentication enabled and Asp.Net Impersonate enabled. In web.config I have <identity impersonate="true" /> and <authentication mode="Windows" />.

Now the User.Identity.Name gives me IUSR. I want User.Identity.Name to give me the user's username to windows

Comment: Turn anonymous authentication off then. You also do not need impersonation.

Comment: I have disabled anonymous authentication on the iis as well as asp.net impersonation. I have also removed <identity impersonate="true" /> from web.config. It still prompts me for credentials.

Comment: If you give it your domain credentials when it asks, does it work? If so, then Windows Authentication is working.

Comment: To make the browser send your credentials without asking you, you need to add your site to the Trusted Sites or Intranet Sites list in the Windows Internet Options.